# Is there way to simply Javascript EventListener using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Javascript code and I'm wondering if I can simplify.

```
    let seattle = svgDoc.getElementById("Seattle");
    seattle.addEventListener("mouseover", hover);
    seattle.addEventListener("mouseout", unhover);
    seattle.addEventListener("click", select);

    let sanJose = svgDoc.getElementById("San_Jose");
    sanJose.addEventListener("mouseover", hover);
    sanJose.addEventListener("mouseout", unhover);
    sanJose.addEventListener("click", select);

    let losAngeles = svgDoc.getElementById("Los_Angeles");
    losAngeles.addEventListener("mouseover", hover);
    losAngeles.addEventListener("mouseout", unhover);
    losAngeles.addEventListener("click", select);

    more cities...
```

When user selects a specific city, I need to disable eventlistener ONLY for that specific city and store the city name (which is also the element id).

```
function select(){
        if(numSelected != 2){
            if(!startSet){start=this.id; startSet = true;}
            else if(!endSet){end=this.id; endSet = true;}
            this.style.fill = "#5cb85c";
            this.removeEventListener("mouseover", hover);
            this.removeEventListener("mouseout", unhover);
            this.removeEventListener("click", select);
            this.addEventListener("click", unselect);
            numSelected++;
        }
    }
```

I read somewhere I can use JQuery to add event listener to all classes
so I can do something like

```
${".cities"}.addEventListener("click", select);
```

But is there a way to get the specific element ID and disable only that element's event listener?

Answer (score 2):

yes.
for starters, I think you have a typo over there. It's `$(".cities")` not `${".cities"}` (parentheses instead of curly braces).

Second of all you might notice that what you pass to the `$()` function is in fact a CSS selector and there are really a lot of these. In the world of CSS if you want to apply a style to an element with a specific class, you use `.`. If you however want to use a specific ID, you indicate it with `#`. So If you have an element with ID 'San_Jose', you can reference it with `$('#San_Jose')`